# Windows 10 File Explorer opens slow

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, performance

This was few months ago, don't mind the text in the video, this was from another issue.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c-NN5Y5Jeqk
And this is now:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A4w2gxpbdUA
You definitely can see the difference, the os is installed on a 250gb Samsung SSD. Sometimes I don't understand windows 10...
Why all of a sudden it is slow to open what could have caused this?
It's the same issue with documents, this pc shortcuts on desktop.
I did a clean install of windows and the problem remained the same.
Windows version is 1511(10586.873)

Comment: This might be a problem with your network - try to temporarily disable the network card and check for improvement.

Comment: didn't solve it.

Comment: When doing the clean install of Windows, did you try it before installing *anything* at all?

Comment: I tried system restore, disk cleanup, different nvidia drivers.

Comment: This is not the same as the clean install of Windows. Was Explorer already slow immediately after it and before any other software was installed?

Comment: I can't remember exactly, but it might not have been slow immediately after install, I might need to try yet another windows version to install..

Comment: If it wasn't slow immediately after install, then the problem is with some product or add-on that you installed.

Comment: update to v1703 (Creators Update) and look if the issue still occurs or not.

Comment: I have done that already, got about 30fps in games and terrible stuttering, plus the problem remained the same. I currently reinstalled v1511 and so far have no problems, but I'm checking the file explorer every step of the way, maybe I will figure out which program might have been causing this all this time.

Comment: The only program I haven't installed yet, that I feel would cause the problem the most is Donotspy10 and I don't want to install it just to check if it's it and potentially mess up windows again...it's a good app though..

Comment: but support for 1511 will end soon. 1507 is out of support in may, so 1511 will follow. try to solve your slowness. also submit it via feedback hub app

Comment: I don't need updates, I just need stable windows that I can work with, I can have windows with no updates for years, in fact I have a windows 7 laptop with the same windows version for 5 years now, not a single problem..

Comment: so you also drive your car without seatbelt? new builds bring new features and security improvements.

Comment: fix one issue, introduce another..

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be related to the Shell Extensions. You could remove some applications off of my computer and used ShellExView to disable all of the Shell Extensions that weren't made by Microsoft to check.
Also disable Quick Access in File Explorer to check.

Comment: The interesting thing is I reinstalled windows couple times and the issue remained the same and the third time while I was installing it I formated that small partition called "System reserved" which was 500mb, then booted windows and so far the problem disappeared, so it's all good for now, let's hope it stays that way..